# Fail to launch multiple setInterval

Tags: javascript, animation, timer, setinterval

I am building a function to update a HTML node's background position at a regular basis. The function works for a single node, but when called upon multiple node (in the following example), only the last node is affected by this function.

According to the **alert(index)** within the function, setInverval() is called for each node.

I cannot figure out why it doesn't take effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/GqNgs/1/

```
var bgImgAnimate = function (settings) {
    $.each(settings.nodeList, function (index, node) {
        thisNode = $(node);

        var thisPosition;

        setInterval(function () {
                    alert(index);
        //calculate the position before position the image

            thisPosition = - settings.frameWidth * settings.currentFrame;

            thisNode.css('backgroundPosition', (thisPosition + 'px') + ' ' + (settings.verticalPos + 'px'));


        }, settings.interval);      
    });


};

var settings = {
    nodeList: $('#star1, #star2, #star3'),
    verticalPos: 0,
    currentFrame: 1,
    frameWidth: 26,
    startTime: 2,
    frameNumber: 10,
    interval: 200
}

bgImgAnimate(settings);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `thisNode` is global, so once you execute your function you quickly loop through all three elements (what you call nodes), but when that's done, all three functions that will execute at the interval will refer to *a single* element (and therefore only that one will be changed, the fact that your alerts showed you the correct answer, is because each alert references a differently and correctly scoped `index` value).

Simple fix, change:

```
thisNode = $(node);
```

to:

```
var thisNode = $(node);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GqNgs/2/

As an aside, it would probably be more scalable to set only one interval function, and each time it's called move the background (or do whatever manipulation you want) on all elements, rather than an interval for each element.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of you iterate nodeList and you ASSIGN *thisNode* each time and then you pass it to the interval. But what happens is that *thisNode* is three times rewrited (after the loop it reffers to the LAST node) and **AFTER** that three intervals are executed all with the same *thisNode* variable which at the moment is the LAST node.